# Basic Selenium Project Invalid Argument Error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm just getting into Selenium, and in my test program it's coming up with this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
```

`(Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.106)`

This is all I've typed:

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("www.musiciansfriend.com")
```

A chrome window pops up but it only says " data:, " in the URL. 
It also says this:

```
[10692:9544:0619/154112.340:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(208)] [15:41:12.340] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1060 Getting Default Adapter failed.
```

I think it'll be some simple fix, but I can't think of it/ Selenium and chromedriver are installed and are the correct version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like selenium doesn't append https://

```
driver.get("https://www.musiciansfriend.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

don't type url into your code please copy url from browser and paste with http

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue A chrome window pops up but it only says " data:, " in the URL. It also says invalid argument .this:Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.106. For me the strange thing is it happens only when I start tests from Bamboo server.When I start from my local on to remote machine it works fine. ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.30 is available. Try with that and let me know if it works.

Comment: My issue was just me being stupid and not putting "https://" on the URL. I'm pretty sure I'm using ChromeDriver 83 because that's my current version of Chrome. I'm not very knowledgeable on working with local and remote machines so I really couldn't tell you why that was happening.